# General questions about RSSI for wireless devices

Tags: ieee-802.11

Received Signal Strength Indicator (RSSI) is a measure of the received signal power at the antenna and is usually a negative number expressed in dbm for IEEE 802.11 devices.

My questions are:

1. Does RSSI take account the power of noise? Or is it just power of the signal? If it doesn't take into account power of noise, then how can one distinguish whether there is noise or not?
2. Does RSSI take into account the transmit and receive antenna gain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does RSSI take account the power of noise? or is it just power of the signal? If it doesnt take into account power of noise, then how can one distinguish whether there is noise or not?

It is simply an indication of signal strength. Noise is a separate measure and not all 802.11 devices are capable of detecting or providing this information.

Note that in 802.11, the standard does not define any relationship between RSSI and any specific value, such as mW or dBm. Vendors are free to use whichever arbitrary scale the choose to represent RSSI, although many of them have chosen to represent this in dBm.

> Does RSSI take into account the transmit and receive antenna gain?

No. It is measure of the strength of the signal it receives. A higher gain antenna would simply result in a higher RSSI as the signal would be stronger.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been helpful, does the RSSI measure the power of the whole received packet from the preamble to the data field?

Comment: As I understand it, no. This is typically based off the preamble, as this is a relatively simple matter.  Calculating based on the whole received packet would usually provide a range of values and may require more specialized hardware.  The standard doesn't define how to measure RSSI, so often the manufacturers will take the easiest path.

Comment: Thanks again. Feel free not answer my question in this comment but I was wondering is RSSI similar to RCPI (received channel power indicator)?

Comment: RCPI is largely defined in 802.11k and is intended as a replacement of RSSI in 802.11. Unlike RSSI, it does measure the signal over the entire preamble/frame and the standard does set out specifications for measuring and accuracy of the signal strength.

Comment: so major different, is that one includes the power over the whole frame and RSSI doesn't?

Comment: More accurately, RCPI includes the power over the whole preamble/frame, RSSI doesn't define how it is measured so it may or may not (although typically not).

Comment: when you write preamble/frame (you mean preamble or frame)? or preamble is same as frame?

Comment: Sorry shouldnt have asked last questiom, thanks for all details

Comment: Frame is L2, preamble is L1. They go hand in hand, but are not the same thing.

Comment: I have one more question. You mentioned regarding my second question that a RSSI is NOT function of antenna gain. However in your answer you say if we have higher gain antenna than we have higher RSSI? How come then its not a function of the gain? I hope you can help me clarify that

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the meaning of your question, or wasn't clear in my answer. RSSI doesn't take into account the actual gain of the antenna, as in it isn't calculated with any knowledge of what the antenna's gain is. You could change the antenna to one with a different gain and this makes no difference to how the RSSI is calculated, it just changes the end result. Another way, it is simply the measure of the signal strength, so while a higher gain antenna will typically produce a higher signal strength or RSSI, the calculation itself takes no notice of the antenna's actual gain.

Comment: Thank in you opinion, wouldnt it be better to have RSSI include the antenna gain. Since RSSI is being used by devices to signal or feedback this field for example there is a  field called Last_RSSI. If gain of antenna is not included, then the real net gain is not being signalled.

Comment: I don't understand your question. An antenna is a passive device, it can't signal anything and an antenna cannot indicate to a driver/device it's gain. Yet another way, when a device is calculating RSSI it doesn't care about the antenna at all (or even if there is one), it is calculating only based on the signal strength it receives. While the presence or type of antenna will change the signal strength, RSSI only cares about that signal strength. It seems you are dragging this way out of scope for this site again and may need to look elsewhere for your answers.

Comment: Thanks, can you please give me some ideas of which Sites can help with such questions. In particular questions related to WLAN and IEEE802.11 @Ylearn. I think the electrical engineering SE is also not the right site.

Comment: Perhaps someplace like safaribooksonline.com but I wouldn't know off hand as I have not delved as deeply into L1 wireless as you seem to want to go.